# I can't get a right data type with print command

Tags: python, types, printing

I don't know why didn't get the type print. The print type keeps coming out as str.Please help me[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScQ5q.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPrUW.jpg)

Comment: `str` means string which is correct. What are you expecting?

Comment: more context needed

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you have defined `my_variable` twice on lines 1 and 18. My understanding is that you only need to have the print statement on line 21, so line 18 (and lines 19 - 20 too) should probably be removed.

The comments indicate that before the code is executed, the value of `my_variable` will be changed to test for different possible data types, so that's all you need to do.

Here is an example to understand datatypes:

```
print(type("Hello, world!")
```

gives you:

```
<class 'str'>
```

`str` corresponds to a 'string' datatype. You can learn more about strings [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string).

```
print(type(3.4))
```

gives you:

```
<class 'float'>
```

while

```
print(type(3)
```

gives you:

```
<class 'int'>
```

but:

```
print(type(3.0))
```

gives

```
<class = 'float'>
```

`int` is for integers and `float` is for float, learn more [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/numbers).

Moreover,

```
print(type(False))
```

or

```
print(type(True))
```

gives:

```
<class 'bool'>
```

`bool` stands for boolean, which can only have values `True` or `False`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please do NOT post code as image, it is very uncomfortable
2. Please give more context in the future :)

Answer:
You do not need to put `my_variable = "Hello, world!"` second time after the big comment, because as far as I can see, the program will only edit the first line and check if type of `my_variable` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific type "print" the output of the type() is the Datatype of the variable.
Learn more about it here ([Python type() Function][1]
[1]: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_type.asp